# r - apply binary vector mask on vector

Tags: r

How to filter vector `v` with mask `m` as example below?

```
v = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
m = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
# apply mask m on v (0 should subtract element)
maskedVector # [1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: `v[m!=0]` or `v[!!m]` are some options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your `m` vector to a logical object and use it to index `v`.

```
   v = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
   m = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

   v[as.logical(m)]
   [1] 1 4 5
```

Comment: same as `v[which(m==1)]`